# How to expand Mat Table grid to the thrid level in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a Mat-Table with nested grid with a nested json . It has 2 grids for now .
But now i have a requirement where i need an additional nested grid inside .

I tried to replicate what is done for the second level grid to generate the third level grid but the "ExpandedElements" array throws an error while generating the third level grid .

My updated JSON looks like -

```
{
name: 'Mason',
email: 'mason@test.com',
phone: '9864785214',
addresses: [
  {
    street: 'Street 1',
    zipCode: '78542',
    city: 'Kansas',
    comments: [
      {
        commenID: 1,
        comment: 'Test',
        commentStatus: 'Open'
      },
      {
        commenID: 2,
        comment: 'Test',
        commentStatus: 'Open'
      },{
        commenID: 3,
        comment: 'Test',
        commentStatus: 'Closed'
      },
    ]
  },
```

I want the comments to be an internal grid under address grid .

I have the 2 grids ready with the json in the stackblitz link -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-sia2jn?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts

Can anyone help me how to proceed with the third level of grid ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited your Stackblitz for a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.html

Added the additional table and added bools directly on the datasource to show what is expanded and not (instead of the list functions). Also using simple arrays instead of dataSource. :)

---

On the div inside the table data:

```
<div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element?.expanded"  *ngIf="element?.expanded">
```

On the row definition:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
    [class.example-element-row]="element.addresses?.length" [class.example-expanded-row]="element?.expanded"
    (click)="element.expanded = !element?.expanded">
</tr>
```

It checks for the key **expanded** on element. The question mark is a null check, so if the key does not exist - element?.expanded returns undefined.

Also, when clicking the row, element.expanded is set to !element?.expanded. When clicking the first time, element?.expanded is undefined and adding an exclamation point in front of that inverts it - essentially setting it to true. Next time you click it will be set to the opposite of true - which is false. :)

There is no need to add it to the JSON directly, the bools will be added as needed when clicking the table.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by this "added bools directly on the datasource to show what is expanded and not (instead of the list functions)." . I cant see any change made to the JSON , no bools are added for expanded .

Comment: Updated the answer - there is no need for changing the JSON directly (that is why you don't see it there, look in the template instead), the bools are added when needed (clicking in the template).

Comment: Can you look into this question please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160846/mat-table-data-source-getting-overridden-when-applied-on-nested-grids-in-angular